# cannot print a variable in swift

Tags: ios, class, swift, variables, println

I wrote the code that is shown below. How can I print A4 variable?
When I try like that I get an error?

Error: __lldb_expr_1.Paper

```
// Paper Factory
// All sizes are mm type
import UIKit


class Paper {
    var weight: Double = 0.0
    var sizeHeight: Double = 0.0
    var sizeWidth:  Double = 0.0

    init(weight: Double, sizeHeight: Double, sizeWidth: Double){
        self.sizeHeight = sizeHeight
        self.sizeWidth = sizeWidth
        self.weight = weight
    }

    func paperPrice(weight: Double, sizeHeight:Double, sizeWidth:Double){
        var price = (sizeHeight * sizeWidth) * weight / 1000
    }
}

var A4 = Paper(weight: 3, sizeHeight: 210, sizeWidth: 297)

println(A4)
```

Comment: http://vperi.com/2014/06/04/textual-representation-for-classes-in-swift/

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
 NSLog("\(A4)")
```

It's working fine...

Answer (score 0):

In the error message, `lldb` refers to LLDB, i.e. Xcode debugger's command line prompt. The correct way to print these values is to use `NSLog` with [format specifiers](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004265). For example:

```
NSLog(@"Value of property : %d", A4.weight)
```

Also, looking at your sample code above, `price` is not accessible at class level, because it's defined within the scope of `func paperPrice`. You may want to define `price` similarly to `weight`, etc. and access with `A4.price`.

Answer (score 0):

`println` works fine your class conform to the `Printable` protocol. Implement your class in that way. Don't forget to add the `description` property.

```
class Paper : Printable{

    var weight: Double = 0.0
    var sizeHeight: Double = 0.0
    var sizeWidth:  Double = 0.0

    var description: String {
        return "Weight: \(weight) sizeHeight: \(sizeHeight) sizeHeight: \(sizeHeight): \(sizeHeight: \(sizeHeight))"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your paperPrice function doesn't do anything. It is setting a value to a variable that is defined within the function. As soon as the function completes, the variable is out of scope. You need to return the variable to something outside the Class to use it. Try this:

```
// Paper Factory
// All sizes are mm type
import UIKit


class Paper {
    var weight: Double = 0.0
    var sizeHeight: Double = 0.0
    var sizeWidth:  Double = 0.0

    init(weight: Double, sizeHeight: Double, sizeWidth: Double){
        self.sizeHeight = sizeHeight
        self.sizeWidth = sizeWidth
        self.weight = weight
    }

    func paperPrice() -> Double {
        var weight = self.weight
        var sizeHeight = self.sizeHeight
        var sizeWidth = self.sizeWidth
        var price: Double = (sizeHeight * sizeWidth) * weight / 1000
        return price
    }
}


var A4paper = Paper(weight: 3, sizeHeight: 210, sizeWidth: 297)
var price = A4paper.paperPrice()

println(price)
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the function that calculates the paperPrice returns a value that can be printed.

```
return price
```